# PHP can not send the mails from live.com smtp

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send the mails from my PHP page. I am using the live.com SMTP server to send the mails from my live account. When I try to send the mail from PHP I am receiving the error

```
Error: SMTP Connect() failed.
```

What may be the problem?

Here is my mail configuration.

```
define("EMAIL_USE_SMTP", true);
define("EMAIL_SMTP_HOST", "smtp.live.com");
define("EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH", true);
define("EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX@live.com");
define("EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD", "XXXXXXXXX");
define("EMAIL_SMTP_PORT", 587);
define("EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION", "ssl");
```

I also tried changing the host to `smtp.mail.live.com` and port to `25`, and `465` also but still not working.

Comment: Are you sure that your webserver is setup correctly? For instance xampp requires extra configuration in order for the messages to be sent

Answer (score 0):

Check that the machine firewall is allowing the port and connection

Try telnet from the machine with:

```
telnet smtp.live.com 587
```

Did you get:

```
220 BLU436-SMTP67.smtp.hotmail.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 8.0.92
00.16384 ready at  Fri, 18 Sep 2015 01:06:29 -0700
```

If you get below, try open the machine firewall

```
Could not open connection to the host, on port XXX: Connect failed
```